# How would you go about solving this tricky distance problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

[image]

I've tried calculating the distance the runner has left to get to the finish line by the time the bird gets there and adding it to the distance the bird has to fly back to the runner. Then I multiplied the answer by 2 and got 6.5km. However, my answer was marked incorrect.

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hint: this is just a variant of the classic [two trains problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwoTrainsPuzzle.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also would like to give you a hint. 
Forget about back and forth trip of bird, let it fly straight, until boy reach the finish line and see how far the bird is.
First Calculate ***the time boy takes to reach the finish*** line and then solve for the bird and see ***how far can bird go in that time***.

Even, we can get answer without calculation. Bird's speed twice, so by the time when boy covers 4 km bird will cover as twice as boy. So, From this conclusion our answer becomes 8 km.

Comment: I did solve for that and I got 6.5 km. What did you get?

Comment: Well you can check and verify the answer but it's 8 km